# REGEX on GET request Django

Tags: django, curl, django-views

```
curl --data "value=Mi8h1LdXFbbNnxZp+hgKLA==&key=TheBestSecretKey+" http://domain.com:8888/api/request_back/

**VIEWS.py**
print request.POST.get('value'),request.POST.get('key')

Mi8h1LdXFbbNnxZp hgKLA== TheBestSecretKey

urls.py
url(r'^api/request_back/$', request_back ,name='request_back'),
```

i'm not getting the PLUS regex of values .how its possible

Comment: Try with a `%2B` instead of a `+`.

Comment: @PauloBu , How it can be filled Automatically . 'cse my requests will be from console not from browser , and which will not be typed manually.

Comment: I was only on a hunch, did it worked?

Comment: Its Worked , But urlencode should be done befor POSTING. r8 ?

Comment: Yes, `curl` should be encoding it, let me see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this [`--data-urlencode`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-urlencode):

```
curl --data-urlencode "value=Mi8h1LdXFbbNnxZp+hgKLA==" --data-urlencode "key=TheBestSecretKey+" http://domain.com:8888/api/request_back/"
```

Comment: NO this one will bring only one value for the attribute value

value=Mi8h1LdXFbbNnxZp+hgKLA==&key=TheBestSecretKey+

But the method is Good ..

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand quite well your comment, what happened with that?

Comment: i'm getting entire value like
value=Mi8h1LdXFbbNnxZp+hgKLA==&key=TheBestSecretKey+

instead of



  
value = Mi8h1LdXFbbNnxZp+hgKLA== ,  key= TheBestSecretKey+

Comment: @AnishMenon I make a change, use to `--data-urlencode`s, one for each argument, take a look and try and feed me back :)